# XSLT1.0 Logic on Date Field

Tags: xslt

Input:

```
<Orderdate>130212</Orderdate><!-- date in the form of YYMMDD -->
```

We should consider below points.

The `<Orderdate>` should check with the current date (Today date).

1. If `<Orderdate>` is less than Today date then add 2 days to the current date.

   The below points we should consider

   - example today date is 130602 which is Sunday. We have to add 2 days then it would become 130604.

     output:

     ```
     <Orderdate>130604</Orderdate>
     ```
   - If the Today date is 130531 which is Friday in our case we have to exclude Saturday and Sunday, so the date would become 130604.

     output:

     ```
     <Orderdate>130604</Orderdate>
     ```
   - If the Today date is 130530 which is Thursday adding 2 days become Saturday (execlude Saturday, Sunday), so the date would become 130603.

     output:

     ```
     <Orderdate>130603</Orderdate>
     ```
2. If the `<Orderdate>` is greater than current date (Today date)

   We have to get as it is same value in the output.

   input:

   ```
   <Orderdate>130608</Orderdate>
   ```

   output:

   ```
   <Orderdate>130608</Orderdate><!-- which is greater than today date so direct value in the output -->
   ```

Comment: In your two months on this site you have *never* asked a question that shows any sign that you have tried to solve the problem yourself. You are treating Stack Overflow as a place to get software written for free, and that is *not* its purpose. Please take the time to learn XSLT to the point where you can expect to solve these problems for yourself. You should be asking questions here only on the rare occasion where your own knowledge doesn't suffice. At present you are taking on problems that are way beyond your capability and you should stop.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 1.0 has no builtin function for determining the current date. So this has to be passed as a parameter to the stylesheet (per `<xsl:param />`).
For adding days to a specific date you may have a look at http://blog.dlwelch.com/?p=25

Alternatively, depending on your XSLT processor, it might be the best solution to do this entire date arithmetic outside of XSLT (Saxon for example allows the invocation of custom Java methods).

Comment: If (as I understood) only "today" and "today_plus_two_workdays" xsl:param could be use for bot of them.